# change last comma to tab character for each line in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

Can you help me changing

```
abc,abc,12345
```

to

```
abc,abc    12345
```

in vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wasn't so hard to google the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace).

`:%s/.*\zs,/\t/` or `:%s/.*\zs,/^I/`

`:s/old/new/` is the syntax, but vim has aditional features for searching and replacing in particular, `\zsfoobar\ze` let's you select `foobar` for replacing.

In your example `.*`, like in any regex, means any character any number of times, or just "some text that is as long as possible", followed by `,` that is selected with the `\zs` feature. Since it's already the end of the pattern, you don't need to use `\ze`. Then you replace the selected pattern with `\t` AKA the ascii tab symbol.

If you didn't select anything, the whole pattern (including the "some text" part) would be replaced. You can do fine without it and some other regexes, but if you're using a tool or language, might as well use its features.

Comment: Damn that `\z` is powerful, I hadn't heard of it. I guess I'll be using that a lot from now on! -- Inserting `\t` won't work though, you should insert `^I`.

Comment: Cool, i suppose vim has a lot of special meaning for \{character}, so it's not surprising that \t may not work.

Comment: It can but not always, when `expandtab` option is on for instance.

Comment: @andrisleduskrasts If you would elaborate on your answer a little, so the OP fully understands the solution, then I will delete my answer!

Comment: @ShellFish It has nothing to do with `expandtab`.  See `:help s/\t`.

Comment: @lcd047 Oh, apparently you're right, thanks for pointing that out! -- Yet it fails on my [tag:vim], probably a `.vimrc` issue then?

Comment: @ShellFish More likely you have a plugin that does that.  Normally `s/.../...\t.../` inserts a real tab character.  If you have `expandtab` set you _can_ expand the tab by running `:ret!`, but AFAICT this is not done automatically.  Maybe you have some plugin and / or an `autocmd` that does it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Fo the sake of diversity:

```
:%norm $F,r<C-v><Tab>
```

- move to the end of the line
- jump to first comma to the left
- replace it with a `<Tab>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/,\([^,]*\)$/ \1
```

Explanation

```
: ........ command
% ........ entire file
/ ........ start searching
, ........ comma 
\( ....... opening regex group
[^,]* .... anything but comma
\) ....... closing regex group
$ ........ at the end of line
/ ........ end search
Ctrl-v TAB .... to insert tab
\1  ...... back reference to regex group
```